# failing cucumber test , using rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

the fail test show following log
    (::) failed steps (::)

```
No route matches "/wiki/Baltimore_Ravens" (ActionController::RoutingError)
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:20:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
features/annotate.feature:7:in `Given I am on a web page'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/annotate.feature:11 # Scenario: launch annotation/ logged in

56 scenarios (1 failed, 5 skipped, 50 passed)
413 steps (1 failed, 62 skipped, 350 passed)
```

the file named web_steps.rb . line no. 20 is:

```
19 Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
20   visit path_to(page_name)
21 end
```

the file named annotate.feature . line no. 7

```
6 Background:
7   Given I am on a web page
8   And I am logged in
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define  page path in **support/paths.rb** inside **path_to** method like this

```
   when /^a web page$/
   path of web page from rake route commnad
```